# C# - Check if ObservableCollection CollectionChanged Event has finished executing

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection

I have a XML Serializable List, which is of type ObservableCollection.  I have an event implemented so that any time a change is made to this collection, it should be serialized, then deserialized.

There is an external class (Weapons Editor) that can add, delete, and modify weapons.  As soon as the delete button is pressed, it comes to this WeaponsDB class to gather the ObservableCollection.  However, it does its refresh of what's inside the ObservableCollection before my CollectionChanged Event has executed.

How can I ensure that the CollectionChanged event has fully executed and everything is up to date before any other class obtains the most updated data?

```
public class WeaponDatabase
{
    [XmlArray("Weapons"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Weapon), ElementName = "Weapon")]
    public ObservableCollection<Weapon> Weapons = new ObservableCollection<Weapon>();

    private string path = @"Inventory\WeaponsDB.xml";

    public WeaponDatabase()
    {
        DeserializeData();
        Weapons.CollectionChanged += Weapons_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void Weapons_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerializeData();
        DeserializeData();
    }

    public void SerializeData()
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Weapon>));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        Serializer.Serialize(textWriter, Weapons);
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    public void DeserializeData()
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Weapon>));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        Weapons = (ObservableCollection<Weapon>)Serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used an ObservableCollection yet so there's the possibility I'm a touch off-base, but hey.

Likely, your weakness is that you're viewing this backwards. CollectionChanged is what should be fired to let your external object accessing the collection know that the collection is updated, not to be used to update the actual collection (via dumping it out to a file or rebuilding it from an XML file).

To wit:

This external class should have a setup something along the lines of this:

```
    public class WeaponsEditor
    {
        private WeaponsDatabase DB;
        public WeaponsEditor()
        {
            DB = new WeaponsDatabase();
            DB.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        }

        private object CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // respond to the updated database
        }
    }
```

Basically, the CollectionChanged event is for *other objects* to respond to a changed collection, not for your class to make its updates. If the Weapons Editor object is manipulating the collection directly, that's your problem; you should have it call a custom method in WeaponsDatabase, which will forward the request to the collection and then call the Serialize/Deserialize methods immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface to `WeaponDatabase` (I say use that interface instead of a custom event so things like `BindingSources` will automatically just work with it)

```
public class WeaponDatabase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [XmlArray("Weapons"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Weapon), ElementName = "Weapon")]
    public ObservableCollection<Weapon> Weapons {get; private set;}

    private string path = @"Inventory\WeaponsDB.xml";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public WeaponDatabase()
    {
        Weapons = new ObservableCollection<Weapon>();
        DeserializeData();
        Weapons.CollectionChanged += Weapons_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void RaiseWeaponsChanged()
    {
        var temp = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(temp != null)
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Weapons"));
    }

    void Weapons_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerializeData();
        DeserializeData();
        RaiseWeaponsChanged()
    }

    //Snip
}
```

Now other classes can subscribe to the `WeaponDatabase.PropertyChanged` event and be notified when the collection changed and the deserialization is complete.